# I get it. I can find answers with the help of AI. Can you stop bugging me now?

Tags: bug, status-completed, overflow-ai

I see there is a new popup telling me that I can find answers more quickly with the help of AI. However, once I close it, after I go to a new page, it pops up again. This is similar to [search bar flashing issue](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426892/20153035). However, unlike the search bar flashing issue, this obstructs content, preventing me from seeing part of an answer until I close it. Is this intended? If so, how do I disable it?

[image]

Comment: just try it! try it now!

Comment: Hmm, I don't see that. Do you have OverflowAI Search enabled in your preferences by any chance (Or maybe I am seeing some cache)?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it only appears if you have overflowai search enabled and you've been selected to participate.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I do. I have opted in to the preview. I would assume (unless made public) you wouldn't see this if you weren't opted in.

Comment: Have you clicked the "try it now" button at least once before? They probably use a cookie to determine whether to show it to you again and if you click it I would expect it to update said cookie. Alternatively just opt out of the site experiment if you aren't interested in trying it.

Comment: I haven't tried it. Is it any good?

Comment: @TylerH I clicked it, and it seems to have stopped, however, I'm unsure if it may return or not. However, UX wise, you shouldn't have to give in to make something stop. I should expect if I close it, it's closed for good.

Comment: I attempted to figure out how to reproduce this but failed.  Once it happens, then opening a new tab and navigating to stackoverflow.com again will cause it to occur again.  But after that, it seems to go away for some period of time before activating again.  Some details are at [my duplicate of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427063/1563833)  FYI I also opted into the overflowai participation.

Comment: @Fastnlight I agree with you, but I can also see the logic of "someone explicitly opted _in_ to this experiment, and they haven't actually tried it yet. Keep reminding them to try it until they do", and it's fairly defensible logic.

Comment: @TylerH you have a good point, but we need to remember that this will not always remain opt-in. If this popup kept occurring after the Overflow-AI went live, it would annoy everyone. If this isn't fixed in the preview, how are we to expect it will be fixed live? You rarely see an untested change applied right before something goes live.

Comment: Also, I can confirm clicking the "Try it now" button does not get rid of the popups. I just got it again.

Comment: In my case, the big banner on the home page was stuck there. I just used UBlock: `##.js-ai-search-alpha-banner`

Comment: "how do I disable it?" As always by using an appropriate browser addon with a custom blocking rule. No idea how the modern internet world is supposed to work without them.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I don't use any blockers. I simply immediately leave and don't visit the size again, if it is obnoxious.

Comment: @Dharman Define good. Does it make you laugh hysterically? Yes, it does. If that is what you need at the time then it is pretty good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

thanks for reporting this bug. We deployed a fix just a few moments ago, clicking the 'X' or the blue button should no longer display the popup anymore if you're in the OverflowAI Search alpha.

I'll go ahead and mark the post with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

If you continue to see the popup, please reply to this answer directly and we'll investigate it further. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: The issue has regressed for me to the popup appearing on every screen again. I have both dismissed it and clicked through.

Comment: me two...  

I have dismissed the popup a dozen or more times, and have clicked into the suggested popup 5+ times.   

This is frustrating.  

SO is SOOO good, and this annoying little pop up is SOOO bad.   

I'm ready to just brute force it and try AmerllicA 's answer...

Answer (score 6):

Client-side fix:

1. Install an extension on your web browser (Mine is Chrome and my extension is [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/run-javascript/lmilalhkkdhfieeienjbiicclobibjao))
2. Write and save the following code for the Stack Overflow URL

```javascript
document.getElementById('popover-new-community-labs-search')?.remove();
```

Definitely, the Stack Overflow developers must add a feature that makes this button disappear forever after clicking it. But temporarily, we can use this way to remove this annoying pop-up.