# How long must I endure this AI Search: "Try it now" popup?

Tags: support, bug, popup

I have seen and dismissed this popup so many times it's getting annoying. It is being presented to me many times per day.  It goes away for a session or two, but a few windows and tabs later, it gets shown to me again.  It seems like there's just no way to acknowledge it in a way that gets rid of it for good.

**I'm well aware of the new feature, thanks. Now let's move on.  :)**

Could this be a bug that it's being shown to me so often, or is the repeated notification intentional?

[image: New: Community Labs Search popup]

The text of the popover:

> New: find answers more quickly with the help of AI.
>
> Try it now

I've put some effort into trying to figure out what is causing it to recur, but I'm just not sure yet.   At least one time I was able to open a new tab with Ctrl+T and each time I navigated to stackoverflow.com it showed the popover.  But then when I dismissed it with the X, no further new tabs would make it show.  But then some time later it seems to come back.  So there may be a timing component to it that makes it difficult to reproduce by interaction alone.  I am not blocking cookies or clearing my storage or changing sessions or users.  I do navigate back to the site.  I can't 100% put my finger on what the steps to reproduce are.

The element has the id `popover-new-community-labs-search`.  And in case it matters, I'm using Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: Oddly, I've only seen it once, dismissed it, and never seen it again. The "Search" option doesn't even appear in the Labs section of the side menu.

Comment: "How long..." Nobody knows the future but judging by how important it seems to the company, I'd say, very long.

Comment: Until management replaces the entire site with a chatbot (/s (i hope))