# How can I prevent the AI search popup?

Tags: support, overflow-ai

Is there a way to disable the prompt for AI search on Stack Overflow?

Several questions on the same topic have been asked already, indicating a strong desire for a way to disable or ignore it.

- [How long must I endure this AI Search: "Try it now" popup?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427063/how-long-must-i-endure-this-ai-search-try-it-now-popup)
- [I get it. I can find answers with the help of AI. Can you stop bugging me now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427062/i-get-it-i-can-find-answers-with-the-help-of-ai-can-you-stop-bugging-me-now)

[image: Popup]

Is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Let's instead upvote and/or wait for an answer/response in the post "[I get it. I can find answers with the help of AI. Can you stop bugging me now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427062/i-get-it-i-can-find-answers-with-the-help-of-ai-can-you-stop-bugging-me-now). Just because there is "*a strong desire for a way to disable or ignore it.*", there is no need to repeat the same question.

Comment: Asking more questions in an attempt to get an answer seems like hitting the elevator button extra times to make it go faster.l