# How to disable "Ask with AI" pop-up

Tags: bug, status-review, overflow-ai

I don't want to try now **Ask with AI**. Is there a way, without using ad-blockers / user style / user scripts, to avoid having the pop-up shown every time I open Stack Overflow?

[image: Ask with AI pop-up]

- Sidebar element text

  - Ask with AI
- Pop-up text

  > New: find answers more quickly with the help of AI.
  > Try it now

---

I have been working on adapting an open-source demo to my needs. I have found *hacky* solutions to several of the problems I'm facing, but I want to understand why the hacky solution works and how to implement something elegant, so I'm openening Stack Overflow questions by using different "normal" methods:

- Clicking a link on Google search results
- Opening a new tab by clicking a link on Stack Overflow pages.
- etc.

Today, Sunday, March 31, 2024, every time that I open https://stackoverflow.com, an emerging / temporary UI element shows, pointing to the sidebar option **Ask with AI**. This is very disruptive to my workflow.

I'm using Mac Mini M1, with Chrome and Safari. All are up to date.

I already clicked the **Close** (X) button in the pop-up.

I'm using Node.js in Visual Studio Code to host websites and run web apps at localhost. To "reset" the *end user experience*, when needed, I clear the localhost cookies and logout of Stack Overflow as I'm "playing" with the Stack Exchange API GET /me end-point.

---

From the comments

- [I get it. I can find answers with the help of AI. Can you stop bugging me now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427062/1595451), created 4 months ago. H/T 
  [Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat)

  - This question has [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). I will let the Stack Overflow Meta experts change [support](/questions/tagged/support) to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) as I don't know if this is appropriate to do in this case.
  - This question has an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427083/1595451) also created four months ago suggesting a browser extension and userscript, but I would like to use something else for a while. Today, I'm in the *no hacky solutions* mood.

---

If the answer is "there is no way for end-users to solve this without *a hack*", it's fine. Also, if the answer is to disable JavaScript or something more elegant than using an extension and userscript.

One of the reasons that I'm trying to avoid extensions is that they might make it more complex to debug the stuff I'm working on (web apps). I'm open to using a different web browser or a specific user profile for research / using Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a bug which was previously fixed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427062/i-get-it-i-can-find-answers-with-the-help-of-ai-can-you-stop-bugging-me-now you might want to change the support tag to the bug tag.

Comment: I'm not sure how many people even get this lab to try out. I do not. Maybe you should click the try it out button and see if it stays afterwards.